# Cannot revert after merge in Git

Tags: git, merge, revert

This is my situation. I'm working on the MiniMaxAB branch (green line)

[image]

I accidentally merged a branch (purple) into mine (green) and pushed it. Which is stupid (i just started learning git) and bad for our goal. Now i would love to revert this and undo this merge. Therefore i picked up the hash of the latest commit in the green branch before the merge (which is not visible in this chart because 15days old) and tried to revert:

```
git revert 86ed202152e719ae719654f7805bd2991f63fd29
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work...
This is what git says:

[image]

So i tried with reset, which works

```
git reset 86ed202152e719ae719654f7805bd2991f63fd29
```

But when i push, i get this error:

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: I sure that you have "unmereged" files (there are some conflict files, you not yet manually merged it). change your show `git status` for us

Comment: Here is the git status after the reset: https://gyazo.com/f2f07895c0ddf68b6b3536e7d2ffd754

Comment: I think `revert` you're supposed to say the commit to undo, not the one to revert to. For `reset` then `push`, it doesn't like it because you've changed the history. You can force it to push with `git push -f` but this might be a bad idea if your collaborators have already pulled your update.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the steps below:

Step 1: Manually merge your conflict file `minmax_ab_engine.e` and `ticktactoe.e`
(Open those files and edit them)

Step 2: Add to stage by `git add -A`

Step 3: Commit those files by `git commit -m 'merge conflict files`

Step 4: Pull the update from the remote by `git pull origin MiniMaxAb`

Step 5: Push your update to remote `git push origin MiniMaxAb`

In case you want to revert, you can bypass step 4,5